# VHDL parse error, unexpected INTEGER_LITERAL, expecting RETURN or IDENTIFIER or RSQBRACK Process "Check Syntax" failed

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am writing a VHDL Program for 4:1 MUX and am facing a error on the line where process clause starts

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mux_41 is
    Port ( inp : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 3);
           outp : out  STD_LOGIC;
           sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));
end mux_41;

architecture Behavioral of mux_41 is

begin
    Process(inp[0],inp[1],inp[2],inp[3],sel[0],sel[1])
        begin
            if(sel = "00")
                then outp <= inp[0];
            elsif(sel = "01")
                then outp <= inp[1];
            elsif(sel = "10")
                then outp <= inp[2];
            else outp <= inp[3];
            end if;
        end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Is this the right way to pass sensitivity list to process?

Answer (score 4):

In VHDL when you want to access to a particular element of an array (std_logic_vector are array), you have to use () instead of [].

```
Process(inp(0),inp(1),inp(2),inp(3),sel(0),sel(1))
  begin
    if(sel = "00")
      then outp <= inp(0);
    elsif(sel = "01")
      then outp <= inp(1);
    elsif(sel = "10")
      then outp <= inp(2);
    else outp <= inp(3);
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP doesn't show the complete error message.

It appears to be in the sensitivity list for the process where `inp` is a *signal*_name and the particular parser doesn't use syntactic predicates:

IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.2 Wait statements

> sensitivity_list ::= *signal_name* { , *signal*_name }

and here the selected names (8.3) are all static names (8.1) and all the elements of both `sel` and `inp` are evaluated in the process if statement (10.8) and should be included in the sensitivity set (10.2).

1.3.2 Syntactic description

> The form of a VHDL description is described by means of context-free syntax using a simple variant of the Backus-Naur form (BNF); in particular:
>
> > ...
> >     g) If the name of any syntactic category starts with an italicized part, it is equivalent to the category name without the italicized part. The italicized part is intended to convey some semantic information. For example, *type*_name and *subtype*_name are both syntactically equivalent to name alone
> >     ...

It's possible to write a parser that uses a symbol table containing declarations of named entities (which precede the use of a name in a description). It simplifies both syntactical and semantic analysis while allowing the rules of visibility and scope to be tracked.

In any event not using syntactic predicates results in a different error message. Instead of an error describing a signal as not having a signature you get an error message saying the signature is malformed or isn't applicable (there are several rules that might be applicable without the syntactic predicates).

The error actually occurs for the first left square bracket.  Selected names uses parentheses (round brackets in parts or Europe) instead of square brackets. Also `inp` by itself has elements 3 ***downto*** 0 or 0 ***to*** 3 (noting `inp : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 3)` has a null range (5.2.1) and no elements).

5.2.1 pargraphs 3 and 4:

> A range specifies a subset of values of a scalar type. A range is said to be a *null* range if the specified subset is empty.
>
> The range **L to R** is called an *ascending range*; if **L** > **R**, then the range is a null range. The range **L downto R** is called a *descending range*; if **L** < **R**, then the range is a null range. ...

With a process sensitivity list a process statement (11.3) is assumed to have a single implicit wait statement as it's last sequential statement. The rule for constructing the sensitivity set for the implicit wait statement in a process statement are found in 10.2 Wait statement, where the implicit wait statement will use the longest static prefix (8.1) of any signal name in the process sensitivity list and would be equivalent to `process (sel, inp)`.

11.3 Process statement paragraph 4:

> If a process sensitivity list appears following the reserved word process, then the process statement is assumed to contain an implicit wait statement as the last statement of the process statement part; this implicit wait statement is of the form
>
> **wait on** sensitivity_list ;
>
> where the sensitivity list is determined in one of two ways. If the process sensitivity list is specified as a sensitivity list, then the sensitivity list of the wait statement is that following the reserved word process. ...

10.2 Wait statement paragraphs 3 and 4:

> The sensitivity clause defines the *sensitivity set* of the wait statement, which is the set of signals to which the wait statement is sensitive. Each signal name in the sensitivity list identifies a given signal as a member of the sensitivity set. Each signal name in the sensitivity list shall be a static signal name, and each name shall denote a signal for which reading is permitted. If no sensitivity clause appears, the sensitivity set is constructed according to the following (recursive) rule:
>
> The sensitivity set is initially empty. For each primary in the condition of the condition clause, if the primary is
>
> > — A simple name that denotes a signal, add the longest static prefix of the name to the sensitivity set.
> >     — An expanded name that denotes a signal, add the longest static prefix of the name to the sensitivity set.
> >     — A selected name whose prefix denotes a signal, add the longest static prefix of the name to the sensitivity set.
> >     — An indexed name whose prefix denotes a signal, add the longest static prefix of the name to the sensitivity set and apply this rule to all expressions in the indexed name.
> >     — A slice name whose prefix denotes a signal, add the longest static prefix of the name to the sensitivity set and apply this rule to any expressions appearing in the discrete range of the slice name.
> >     ...
>
> This rule is also used to construct the sensitivity sets of the wait statements in the equivalent process statements for concurrent procedure call statements (11.4), concurrent assertion statements (11.5), and concurrent signal assignment statements (11.6). Furthermore, this rule is used to construct the sensitivity list of an implicit wait statement in a process statement whose process sensitivity list is the reserved word all (11.3).

What this tells us is that the longest static prefix is sufficient in the sensitivity list.

8.1 paragraph 7:

> A *static signal name* is a static name that denotes a signal. The *longest static prefix* of a signal name is the name itself, if the name is a static signal name; otherwise, it is the longest prefix of the name that is a static signal name. ...

With a non-null range for `inp`, using parentheses instead of square brackets your `mux_41 could be expressed`:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux_41 is
    port (
        inp:    in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        outp:   out  std_logic;
        sel:    in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0)
    );
end entity mux_41;

architecture behavioral of mux_41 is
begin
    process (sel, inp)
        begin
            if sel = "00" then
                outp <= inp(0);
            elsif sel = "01" then
                outp <= inp(1);
            elsif sel = "10" then
                outp <= inp(2);
            else 
                outp <= inp(3);
            end if;
        end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

Here with the process sensitivity list supplied with the longest static prefix.

This code will analyze (compile) successfully.